# String between first two (.dots)

Tags: r

Hi have data which contains two or more dots. My requirement is to get string from first to second dot.
E.g `string <- "abcd.vdgd.dhdsg"`

Result `expected =vdgd`

I have used

```
pt <-strapply(string, "\\.(.*)\\.", simplify =  TRUE)
```

which is giving correct data but for string having more than two dots its not working as expected.
e.g `string <- "abcd.vdgd.dhdsg.jsgs"`
its giving `dhdsg.jsgs` but expected is `vdgd`

Could anyone help me.

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 4):

In base R we can use `strsplit`

```
ss <- "abcd.vdgd.dhdsg"
unlist(strsplit(ss, "\\."))[2]
#[1] "vdgd"
```

Or using `gregexpr` with `regmatches`

```
unlist(regmatches(ss, gregexpr("[^\\.]+", ss)))[2]
#[1] "vdgd"
```

Or using `gsub` (thanks @TCZhang)

```
gsub("^.+?\\.(.+?)\\..*$", "\\1", ss)
#[1] "vdgd"
```

Comment: the second solution gives me "dhdsg" with ss = "abcd.vdgd.dhdsg.jsgs"

Comment: @TCZhang Thanks, I just noticed that too. `strsplit` doesn't have those issues. I'll make a correction.

Comment: For the glory of good old regex, use conservative match: `gsub("^.+?\\.(.+?)\\..*$", "\\1", "abcd.vdgd.dhdsg.jsgs")`  # out: vdgd

Comment: @TCZhang Nice! I've added your fixed `gsub` solution (hope you don't mind), and also included a third `gregexpr`+`regmatches` option.

Comment: `sub` is enough here, no need for `gsub`

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
string <- "abcd.vdgd.dhdsg.jsgs"

library(stringr)
str_extract(string = string, pattern = "(?<=\\.).*?(?=\\.)")
[1] "vdgd"
```

I like this one because the `str_extract` function will return the first instance of the correct pattern, but you could also use `str_extract_all` to get all instances.

```
str_extract_all(string = string, pattern = "(?<=\\.).*?(?=\\.)")
[[1]]
[1] "vdgd"  "dhdsg"
```

From here, you could index to get any position between two dots you want.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with the `qdapRegex` package:

```
library(qdapRegex)
ex_between("abcd.vdgd.dhdsg.jsgs", ".", ".")[[1]][1]
# "vdgd"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `read.table` as well if you wish.Here providing the string as given in your problem and selecting the separator as dot("."), Once the column is converted into a data.frame, you may choose to select whatever column you want to pick(In this case it is column number 2).

```
read.table(text=string, sep=".",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[,2]
```

**Output:**

```
> read.table(text=string, sep=".",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[,2]
[1] "vdgd"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fun easy way via `stringr`

```
stringr::word(string, 2, sep = '\\.')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options that are vectorized over the input string vector:

- You can try `tstrsplit` from `data.table`, which is vectorized over `string`:

> ```
> > string <- c("abcd.vdgd.dhdsg", "abcd.vdgd.dhdsg.jsgs")
> > tstrsplit(string, '.', fixed = TRUE)[[2]]
> [1] "vdgd" "vdgd"
> ```

- or regex:

> ```
> > sub('.*?\\.(.*?)\\..*', '\\1', string)
> [1] "vdgd" "vdgd"`
> ```